# turn off web service test page on localhost

Tags: .net, web-services

How can I turn off the HTTP POST test page that is created automatically for web services?

I'd prefer that it not come up if someone enters the .asmx path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<webServices> 
  <protocols>
    <remove name="HttpGet"/>
    <remove name="HttpPost"/>
    <remove name="HttpPostLocalhost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

This should do it.

Comment: I thought the idea was for the default test page that's created, not the whole app?

Comment: @p.campbell this could also go under configuration/location right?